# MySQL Field() sorting

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sort column value appeared in my page like, at first it'll look for active, then pending, then sold,then upcoming. But its showing otherwise. Here is my code

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM custom 
ORDER BY 
    FIELD(status,'Active','Pending','Sold','Upcoming') DESC
```

Comment: Show us an example data set and your desired output.

Comment: its showing sold at first then active then pending then upcoming

Comment: Okay, don't show us an example data set.

Comment: i am looking for active values in column status , if active values are found its showing an image. Then pending found its showing another image. like that

Comment: What part of show us sample data is unclear?

Answer (score 6):

While it's true that `ORDER BY Status` should work, in theory, given that *currently* your desired ordering *happens* to be in alphabetical, and ignoring for a moment that it's not clear what "its not working" means, a more scalable way would be to use a `CASE` expression.

```
ORDER BY CASE Status
  WHEN 'Active'   THEN 0
  WHEN 'Pending'  THEN 1
  WHEN 'Sold'     THEN 2
  WHEN 'Upcoming' THEN 3
END DESC;
```

A more future-proof solution would be a status table with ID, name, and sequence. You join to that table in your query, and order by the sequence. Then you could just change the sequence if you later decide to ask for the data in a different order, and it would be easy to add more status types later, both without having to touch the query. In addition it would allow you to store the id instead of the string, letting you store a lot more data in the same amount of space.

Comment: RESPEK! nice work on the mysql question

Comment: gold [tag:mysql] badge in no time!

Answer (score 2):

Because those status are in alphabetical, you should be able to do

```
SELECT * FROM custom ORDER BY status ASC
```

Comment: @AmirHossain could you try putting together an http://sqlfiddle.com/ to show what is not working as expected. There is some missing data here for this not to work as answered.

Comment: @AmirHossain *What's* not working? Maybe if you showed us what you wanted we could do a better job of *helping* you.

Comment: This isn't very safe because it relies on the ***coincidence*** that the status strings happen to represent the status values in the order the user currently wants. Add a status, BOOM.

Comment: @AaronBertrand and if the op never add's another status's then we have just over complicated the code for no reason, so it is a bit of a gamble either way. I would say adding status's is the least of his worries at the moment, if that basic sql doesn't work.

Comment: Never is a dangerous thing to say. Also consider renaming a status. Why over complicate a future data change? Aside from the intensive labor of copying and pasting a spoon-fed solution, what harm is there in having code that works, even if it is a little more verbose than the code that works at this moment due to sheer convenience? This is not the way you should strive to write code IMHO.